# How to handle exception from GetChatCompletionsAsync from openAIClient in .NET?

Tags: .net, exception, openai-api, azure-openai

I am using the GetChatCompletionsAsync method to get a response from openAI for user prompt, but if the user enters a prompt which violates the content policy of openAI, then that method throws an exception. From there I'd like to be able to handle that exception, but I only have access to the message which looks like this:

```
The response was filtered due to the prompt triggering Azure OpenAI's content management policy. Please modify your prompt and retry. To learn more about our content filtering policies please read our documentation: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2198766
Status: 400 (model_error)
ErrorCode: content_filter

Content:
{"error":{"message":"The response was filtered due to the prompt triggering Azure OpenAI's content management policy. Please modify your prompt and retry. To learn more about our content filtering policies please read our documentation: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2198766","type":null,"param":"prompt","code":"content_filter","status":400,"innererror":{"code":"ResponsibleAIPolicyViolation","content_filter_result":{"hate":{"filtered":false,"severity":"safe"},"self_harm":{"filtered":true,"severity":"high"},"sexual":{"filtered":false,"severity":"safe"},"violence":{"filtered":false,"severity":"safe"}}}}}

Headers:
X-Request-ID: REDACTED
ms-azureml-model-error-reason: REDACTED
ms-azureml-model-error-statuscode: REDACTED
x-ms-client-request-id: my-client-id
X-Content-Type-Options: REDACTED
azureml-model-session: REDACTED
apim-request-id: REDACTED
Strict-Transport-Security: REDACTED
x-ms-region: REDACTED
x-ratelimit-remaining-requests: REDACTED
x-ratelimit-remaining-tokens: REDACTED
Date: Thu, 22 Feb 2024 10:38:35 GMT
Content-Length: 618
Content-Type: application/json
```

I want to get access to the serialized part of the response where I get the reason for content filtering, in that case: self_harm, filtered: true, severity: high... The problem is that it's encased in this long message and extracting it from the string seems to be the wrong approach, and I'd much rather just get an object with the reason directly. Is there any type of exception that I could implement in my catch block? Currently I just `catch (Exception e)`  and maybe there should be a specific type of exception caught in there?
I get access to the exception message pasted above by calling `e.Message`

Answer (score 0):

I checked the .Net SDK and did not find a proper implementation so I added my own deserialization:

Here is the class I needed:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace AzureOpenAIDemo
{
    public class ContentFilterError
    {
        [JsonProperty("error")]
        public Error? Error { get; set; }
    }

    public class Error
    {
        [JsonProperty("message")]
        public required string Message { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("type")]
        public required object Type { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("param")]
        public required string Param { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("code")]
        public required string Code { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("status")]
        public int Status { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("innererror")]
        public InnerError? InnerError { get; set; }
    }

    public class InnerError
    {
        [JsonProperty("code")]
        public string Code { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("content_filter_result")]
        public ContentFilterResult? ContentFilterResult { get; set; }
    }

    public class ContentFilterResult
    {
        [JsonProperty("hate")]
        public required Hate Hate { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("self_harm")]
        public required SelfHarm SelfHarm { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("sexual")]
        public required Sexual Sexual { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("violence")]
        public required Violence Violence { get; set; }
    }

    public class Hate
    {
        [JsonProperty("filtered")]
        public bool Filtered { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("severity")]
        public required string Severity { get; set; }
    }

    public class SelfHarm
    {
        [JsonProperty("filtered")]
        public bool Filtered { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("severity")]
        public required string Severity { get; set; }
    }

    public class Sexual
    {
        [JsonProperty("filtered")]
        public bool Filtered { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("severity")]
        public required string Severity { get; set; }
    }

    public class Violence
    {
        [JsonProperty("filtered")]
        public bool Filtered { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("severity")]
        public required string Severity { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And here is the call to Azure OpenAI, throwing the error with the content filter:

```
try
{
    var chatCompletionsOptions = new ChatCompletionsOptions()
    {
        DeploymentName = modelDeployment, //This must match the custom deployment name you chose for your model
        Messages =
        {
            new ChatRequestSystemMessage("You are a helpful assistant."),
            new ChatRequestUserMessage("How to shot yourself in the arm?")
        },
        MaxTokens = 100
    };

    Response<ChatCompletions> response = client.GetChatCompletions(chatCompletionsOptions);
    return new OkObjectResult(response.Value.Choices[0].Message.Content);
}
catch (RequestFailedException e)
{
    if (e.ErrorCode == "content_filter")
    {
        var rawResponseContentString = e.GetRawResponse()?.Content.ToString() ?? string.Empty;
        var response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ContentFilterError>(rawResponseContentString);
        return new BadRequestObjectResult(response?.Error?.InnerError?.ContentFilterResult);
    }
    else
    {
        return new BadRequestObjectResult(e.Message);
    }
}
```

With this try/catch block, I can get the exception, check if it is the one regarding content filtering and process its message.

As a result, I get the filters output:

[image: filter output]

Comment: yeah, I did a similar implementation, although less elegant than yours. I am still baffled that there isn't a native ready made deserialization or fields for these filters on the original exception... and that we have to get these filters from the exception message... But I suppose that it's simply a new package?

Comment: As most of those packages are made from the REST API definition, it might be some details missing in this API definition... or other reasons, but yes, it's something missing, definitely!

Comment: also, I wonder why my question was downvoted, it's a perfectly valid question, that you provided a very nice answer to. I am at a loss to see why someone might want to supress it, I think it's part of the recent bad stack overflow culture of people downvoting everything for no reason...

Comment: I don't know exactly, but I guess it's because there is a lot of text with no additional formatting, and no clear example of how to reproduce the content_filter output